# Apache settings to serve two sites in different directories

Tags: apache, vhosts, bitnami, concrete5

I am not very good with apache, as I've been an IIS guy for years.

I have two websites in the following directories:
/htdocs/ (site 1)
/htdocs/site2 (site 2)

Doing searches on the web does not give any understandable info on what to do other than a vhost file, etc.  I've tried a few things with no luck.

What file(s) do I need to update so that I can set:
www.site1.com - /htdocs/
www.site2.com - /htdocs/site2

Comment: This is probably not how you want to have your site arranged, you'll be able to navigate to `http://www.site1.com/site2` to see the contents of site2. Instead you should have site1 at `/htdocs/site1`.

Comment: Good point, and I normally do.  Site2 is a sub site of Site1 (Same company), ideally I would/should move.

Comment: If you're just trying to map domains to existing concrete5 pages, check out the domain mapper addon.

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to creating the solution: setting up your virtual hosts and then creating the right document roots for each host.

This can all be done in httpd.conf, but more cleanly as separate files in directory conf.d

So in site-1.conf you'd have these statements:

```
<VirtualHost www.site1.com:80>
ServerName www.site1.com
ServerAdmin me@myemail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/site1.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

And in site-2.conf you'd have this:

```
<VirtualHost www.site2.com:80>
ServerName www.site2.com
ServerAdmin me@myemail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/htdocs/site2
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/site2.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks.  So do I create a site.conf file in the root of the site(s)?

Comment: The main Apache configuration file (in the version of Apache I am using) is in /etc/httpd. Within this directory are two subdirectories "conf" and "conf.d". File conf/httpd.conf is the main configuration file for the server. Installed packages often use conf.d, to drop in additional  configuration files which are read after httpd.conf. Your site1 and site2 conf files would go into conf.d.